# How to set Time picker in Material design Angular 6?

Tags: angular, material-design

I am try to set **time picker module** in material design angular 6 theme but I cannot set because in this theme using **MAT** format for material design.

I had used many module for time picker but in material theme can't set `ng` or `md` or other module.

Comment: I do not understand your question, could you please try to explain what it is that is not working

Comment: Please show what error or exception you are having while using these modules or at least some of your code about how you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

Approach [ignite-ui-angular](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular)

```
npm install -g igniteui-cli
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Here we import the IgxGridModule, so we can use the igxGrid!
import { IgxGridModule } from 'igniteui-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    IgxGridModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

component

// app.module.ts

```
...
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { IgxTimePickerModule } from 'igniteui-angular';

@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [..., BrowserAnimationsModule, IgxTimePickerModule],
    ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

meeting.component.html

```
<igx-time-picker ></igx-time-picker>
```